# Edit (sed) specific line in a file where a string occurs

Tags: bash, shell, search, sed, grep

I have a folder full of textfiles which i want to grep for a specific String, then add a String (let's say a "+ ") via sed at the beginning of that specific line (at all places where the search-String occurs).

So far i got this:

```
if grep -q &MyString /path/to/folder/* ; then
echo "String detected"
sed 's/^/+ /g' -i [what to put in here?]
fi
```

depending on what i put in the brackets it either adds the String in front of every line of every textfile or does nothing because i dont define a correct file. How would i reference the file i detected the String in before?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 grep -l &MyString /path/to/folder/* | uniq | while read line
 do 
     echo "String detected"
     sed '/&MyString/ s/^/+ /g' -i $line
 done
```

Using grep with -l to print just the filename, use uniq to deduplicate and then read each line of the output. Taking each line from the output, use this to represent the filename in sed ($line).

Read line is used as opposed for var in $(grep ...) as this would cause issues for files with spaces in them as each space delimited variable in the output would be used to represent the filename.

Comment: It works as in editing only the file but not the specific line, any suggestions on that?

Comment: Change your sed command to take account of the String you are searching for. I'll edit the answer